# Проигрывание короткого пикающего звука без задержек

Tags: android

Необходимо сделать звуковую сигнализацию (пикающий звук разной частоты пиков, пик - это звук длительностью 100мс) определенного числового значения следующим образом.

Значение x меняется от 0 до 100, в зависимости от x меняется пауза между  пиканиями.

Пробовал через MediaPlayer примерно так

```
while(true) {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Thread.sleep(100 + x); // длина звукового файла 100мс + x (паузы) 
    }
}
```

В итоге время после mediaPlayer.start() и концом проигрывания звука около 300-500мс. SoundPool не пробовал, что-то подсказывает, что результат тот же будет.

Может есть способ сгенерировать звук определенной частоты и длительности непосредственно перед проигрыванием?

Comment: именно `SoundPool` вам должен помочь.

Comment: В SoundPool смутило, что нет функции isPlaying(int streamID). Как узнать, что проигрыване закончено?

Comment: Попробовал сделать также через SoundPool. Если pause < 200мс заметно, что паузы между проигрыванием звука отличаются по длинне, хотя pause постоянна. Но уже лучше, чем вариант с MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите в сторону [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html). перед созданием данного объекта надо будет сгенерировать звук в виде массива байтов. Вот [здесь](http://marblemice.blogspot.ru/2010/04/generate-and-play-tone-in-android.html) есть пример